# Keep a running total

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a list of items in my app that have radio buttons on them. As I change the settings on the radio buttons, I want to update the running total at the bottom of the page. How do I set up the running totals?

Comment: What do you mean by "running total"? The number of items whose radio buttons are filled?

Comment: This question with that rep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has some flaws to it, but it should get you started:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var total = 0;
    function count(input) {
        if(input.checked) {
            total++;
        }
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" onclick="count(this);"/>Radio 1

    <span id="total">0</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was stuck trying to figure out a control to use in jquery mobile. Never occurred to me to use innerHTML. Thanks.